# Undefined value return by Angular

Tags: angularjs, return-value

I have a Angular function to retrieve taxi annonces and i need to calculate the distance between the user connected et the author of annonce then I have something like this :

In my HTML :

```
<main class="main list_page" ng-controller="taxiRechercheCtrl" ng-init="loadRecherche()">
```

In Angular :

```
myApp.controller("taxiRechercheCtrl", ['$scope','$http','$location', 'TaxiService', 'UserService', function($scope, $http, $location, TaxiService, UserService){
    $scope.loadRecherche = function(){
        UserService.getPosition().then(function(position){
            TaxiService.find($scope.recherche).then(function(response){
                $scope.annonces = response.annonces;
                for(var i=0;i<$scope.annonces.length;i++){
                    $scope.annonces[i].Distance = my calculate distance
                }
            }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            });
        }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
        });
    };

    $scope.calculeDistanceGoogle = function(origin, destination){
        var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(origin.Latitude, origin.Longitude);
        var destination1 = new google.maps.LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude);
        var args = {
        origins: [origin1],
        destinations: [destination1],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(args, function(response, status) {
            var elt = response.rows[0].elements[0];
            $scope.distanceTxt = elt.distance.text;
        });
        return $scope.distanceTxt;
    }
}
```

In $scope.annonces[i].Distance = my calculate distance, I want the distance value returned by my calculeDistanceGoogle function.

I tried :

```
$scope.calculeDistanceGoogle($scope.annonces[i].Ville, response.position).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
```

but I have the error : $scope.calculeDistanceGoogle(...).then is not a function.

I tried use $scope.distanceTxt variable, I try directly :

```
var myposition = $scope.calculeDistanceGoogle($scope.annonces[i].Ville, response.position);
```

Comment: What values are you getting in $scope.annonces ?

Comment: Some position values but it's not the problem because I have some value in elt.distance.text then my calculeDistanceGoogle works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$scope.calculeDistanceGoogle(...)` **is not a function that return a Promise**, so you can't call `.then(...)` clause.

And then, this code is wrong:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix(args, function(response, status) {
    var elt = response.rows[0].elements[0];
    $scope.distanceTxt = elt.distance.text;
});
return $scope.distanceTxt;
```

because probabily that service is asynchronous.

**My suggestion is** return a promise with the value of `distanceTxt` as data (add error if present on the promise too).

Comment: My function works, elt.distance.text is defined by the distance that I want. I don't know how to use Promise ?

Comment: I try something like this :
`service.getDistanceMatrix(args, function(response, status) {
          var elt = response.rows[0].elements[0];
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve(elt.distance.text);
          return deferred.promise;
      });`

But same error...

Comment: It's the same if I put `return deferred.promise;` in service.getDistanceMatrix or not

Comment: Anyway in my then function of calculeDistanceGoogle, I have the return of the function calculeDistanceGoogle but i can't affect it to $scope.annonces[i].Distance because outside of then $scope.annonces[i].Distance will be null

Comment: 1. is not the same
2. you miss the point: if service is asynchronous you can't return a value without promise

3. your implementation of promise is not right, return clause should be over of getDistanceMatrix context